# Is it possible to have one android XML layout with a menu footer and load content into it?

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, load, footer

I am writing an Android application, and have recently decided to use a footer menu in the application layout.
Is there a simple way to insert a footer menu into a layout?
And most important, having a footer already set, is there a way to have just one main layout and load the relevant content into it with every menu-option chosen?
Thanks!